# macOS Sonoma GtkAda installed, but Gnat Studio and others do not see it

Tags: macos, ada, gtkada

I have Macs with macOS Sonoma and I have successfully compiled and installed GtkAda from source that I got from AdaCore, with no errors. It's installed at /usr/local/lib/gnat and /usr/local/lib/gtkada, but nothing sees it. I use Gnat Studio and of course it complains about not finding "gtkada" compiling from the command line has the same issue. I have not updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and related because I don't know how if that's the issue. This works on Linux and Windows very easily, but I'm not sure what else to do at this point. I have listed my Macs with Sonoma, but I've actually never had it work with Ventura either, so I don't think that has anything to do with it. I know I'm missing something, and probably something simple.

Answer (score 1):

MacOS equivalent of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Also make sure you have `GPR_PROJECT_PATH` pointing to the directory with `gtkada.gpr`.

Why not use Alire, BTW?

Comment: How do I modify those? Alire seems to be a pain unless I'm not doing it right, but I can't type: "edit" and get Gnat Studio to open.

Comment: Assuming you have the GNATStudio app, this should work: `alr config --global --set editor.cmd 'open -n -a gnatstudio -- ${GPR_FILE}'`

Comment: Once you’ve found the GPR, you shouldn’t need to mess with `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I have Gnat Studio in Applications would I use this same command?

Comment: That worked but my gtkada installation was old and I tried to install 23.0.0 but that is not happening from source or from alr. From source with make install I get: "glib.h not found" From Alire I get: libgtk3>=3.24.24 unavailable. I have been messing around with trying to get a proper gtkada installed on my Macs but I don't think it will ever happen.

Comment: `open -a foo` means "open the application foo, which is in `/Applications`" -- or, if it’s somewhere else, `open -a /where/ever/foo`. Case-insensitive.

Comment: I broke my gtkada installation, so I'm trying it with Alire and this is what I'm trying because I found it elsewhere, but I can't get it to work: alr init --bin hola_gtk    cd hola_gtk    alr with gtkada  When I run this I get:   configure: error: /Users/ryan/.config/alire/cache/dependencies/gprbuild_22.0.1_b1220e2b/bin/gprbuild test failed at compile time! Check your configuration.
error: A post-fetch action failed, re-run with -vv -d for details

Comment: Okay I got the gtkada fixed, but when I try to run the program in Gnat Studio it's looking for glib.h

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (but, the installations have happened in stages, so I may have left out a step or two).

Install the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager.
Include these lines in your startup script (note, I use `bash`, these should be OK in `zsh`):

```
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/lib
```

Open a new Terminal window, type `brew help` to check the  PATH is OK. Close the old window to avoid confusion about what’s on the PATH!

Run `brew install gtk+3`.

You need a native `aarch64` compiler, because the Homebrew package manager knows you’re on Apple silicon and installs `aarch64`, aka `arm64`, binaries.

Install [gcc-13.1.0-aarch64](https://github.com/simonjwright/distributing-gcc/releases/tag/gcc-13.1.0-aarch64-2) - go to the bottom of the page for the `.dmg`. Read the note about setting up your PATH.

Run `alr toolchain --select` -- you should be able to choose `gnat_external=13.1.0` and `gprbuild=23.0.0`.

Now run `alr get gtkada`, and ignore when it says that the solution is incomplete, just accept it (Alire 2.0 will understand Homebrew (and MacPorts) and would run the `brew install` for you).

Now change directory into the new `gtkada_23.0.0_bac4d634` and `alr build`.

Comment: I did these, as you typed them, hopefully I did that right, but I still get the gtk.h not found. I know I have it though.

Comment: I'm actually getting a different problem. CPU type errors.

Comment: The cpu type errors are because there are old x86_64 object files in there. Try in the gtkada_* directory saying `make distclean`, then `alr build`.

Comment: The file `shared.gpr` should contain a variable `Gtk_Include` including the string `"-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.38/include/gtk-3.0"`, the actual include is `<gtk/gtk.h>`

Comment: When I do: make distclean and then alr build it fails just about immediately with the errors:  gtkada.gpr:75:29: "Shared" is not an imported or extended project.    gtkada.gpr:78:30: unknown package or project "Shared".     I'm not 100 percent sure what to do with that path, do I put it in my .zprofile?

Comment: So sorry, I left out a step which would set things up so `alr build` would find what it needs, including `shared.gpr` --

make distclean ; **alr update**;  alr build

Can’t blame you for feeling confused.

Comment: I tried these steps, but I'm still getting the "cputype" errors. I tried: alr get gtkada   make distclean.  alr update.  I add the gtk.h text to shared.gpr   alr build. and then it fails with the cputype.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255777/discussion-between-ryan-pochmara-and-simon-wright).